# Toggle class on click directive?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-directives

Is there a way to add and remove a class using a directive when an element is clicked?

I want to avoid putting the element into a template and just use a directive.

So something like:

```
<div v-toggle-class></div>
```

Then this would toggle a predefined class like `.active`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [custom directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html) and attaching to the click event there (in the `bind` hook).

EDIT: modified to use the element data context to store the class active flag

Just a quick example:

```
Vue.directive("toggle-active", {
  bind: function(el, binding, vnode) {
    el.addEventListener(
      "click",
      () => {
        let active = vnode.context.class_active;
        active = !active;
        vnode.context.class_active = active;
        if (!active) {
          el.classList.remove("active");
          el.classList.add("not-active");
        } else {
          el.classList.remove("not-active");
          el.classList.add("active");
        }
      },
      false
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you provide an example? Something like this? el.addEventListener('click', () => {el.classList.toggle('my-style')});